# Casting generics parameters

Tags: c#, generics

Can you explain why first line of code it give me compiler error and next one not.

```
public void DoStuff<T>(T obj)
{
 Int32 x = (Int32) obj; // 1. Error
 Int32 y=(Int32)(Object)obj; //2. Works fine
}
```

Comment: obj is of type T when you pass it, not the type Object, so you have to cast it to object before. If you use Object instead of T, both lines will work fine.

Comment: Not sure why, but it doesnt seem like a good idea to try. How do you know that cast wont fail at runtime? why not use a Int32.TryParse or event Convert.ToInt32?

Answer (score 4):

In order to cast, you need to know at compile-time how to cast from one type to another. For example:

```
long l = 34;
int i = (int)l;
```

This works because the compiler knows how to cast a `long` to an `int`. It also knows how to convert `object` to `int`:

```
object o = 42;
int i = (int)o;
```

However, not all types can be cast to `int`:

```
string s = "48";
int i = (int)s; // This will not compile.
```

Since your generic can represent any type, you can't just cast to an `int` all willy-nilly for any type. You have to first cast it to something that can be cast to `int`. Since anything can be cast to `object`, and `object` and be cast to anything, your double-cast will work.

Comment: @Wjdavis5 has a good point in his comment - this will only work if your object really is an `int` - and if you know that upfront, then you don't need the `T` in the first place. If it's a fuzzy match (possibly a string or a double or something), then `Convert.ToInt32` probably is a better approach.

Comment: This answer seems to be mixing up the terms "cast" and "convert".

Comment: @Joe I agree. The generics should be used only if the passed types can execute the lines of code without any kind of error. I think just an instanceOf can resolve his issue.

Comment: @Servy Please clarify what you mean. A "Cast" is either an [explicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105(v=vs.120).aspx) like `(int)l` or an [unbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) like `(int)o` - the first one is a conversion, but the conversion happens through a cast (my verbiage may be a little off). The `Convert.ToInt32` comment is not a cast of course, if that's what you're referring to.

Comment: You don't *cast* a long to an int.  You *convert* a long to an int, even using the syntax that you showed.  That is a part of what makes that syntax confusing; it is used both for casting and for certain types of *converting*.

Comment: @Servy I guess it just depends on your definition of `cast`. The [C# Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105(v=vs.120).aspx) seems to define a cast as an "Explicit conversion", and I've always seen the `(Foo)x` syntax described as casting. Maybe that's just a C# term as opposed to a CLR term.

Comment: Casting is the specific cast of taking a reference and treating it as a type different than what it really is, without changing the object that it refers to in any way.  Converting is changing the actual object that the reference refers to.  `(int)somelong` isn't treating a reference as something else, it's changing the actual value, `(ISomeInterface)someclassReference` isn't changing the object that `someclassReference` points to, it's just allowing the compiler (and not the runtime) to treat it differently.

Comment: @Servy That's a very clear explanation, thanks. I think the C# team needs to find a name for the `(SomeType)x` syntax then, because Microsoft uses the word "cast" all over their own documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Casting a generic type variable to another type is illegal unless you are casting to a     type compatible  with a constraint:

```
 private static void CastingAGenericTypeVariable1<T>(T obj) {
Int32 x = (Int32) obj; // Error
String s = (String) obj; // Error
}
```

The compiler issues an error on both lines above because T could be any type, and there is no
guarantee that the casts will succeed. You can modify this code to get it to compile by casting to Object first:

```
    private static void CastingAGenericTypeVariable2<T>(T obj) {   
   Int32 x = (Int32) (Object) obj; // No error
   String s = (String) (Object) obj; // No erro``r
  }
```

While this code will now compile, it is still possible for the CLR to throw an      InvalidCastException at runtime.

If you are trying to cast to a reference type, you can also use the C# as operator. Here is code modified to use the as operator with String (since Int32 is a value type):

```
 private static void CastingAGenericTypeVariable3<T>(T obj) {
  String s = obj as String; // No error
  }

This is from CLR via C#
```

Answer (score 0):

`T` can be any type, but compiler recognizes that hard cast to `Int32` will work only for certain types, hence compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

**If you have a generic method you probably don't want to cast to an int.**  There is almost certainly a better way to do this via overloads or some other approach.

However... if you decide you need to do this you could do either of the following two methods safely...

```
if (obj is Int32)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

or..

```
Int32? z = obj as Int32?
if (z != null)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The specification explains this behaviour:

**6.2.7 Explicit conversions involving type parameters**

> The above rules do not permit a direct explicit conversion from an
>   unconstrained type parameter to a non-interface type, which might be
>   surprising. The reason for this rule is to prevent confusion and make
>   the semantics of such conversions clear. For example, consider the
>   following declaration:

```
class X<T>
{
    public static long F(T t) {
        return (long)t;             // Error 
    }
}
```

> If the direct explicit conversion of t to int were permitted, one
>   might easily expect that X.F(7) would return 7L. However, it
>   would not, because the standard numeric conversions are only
>   considered when the types are known to be numeric at binding-time